# Not able to write/read on internal or external storage

Tags: android, file, storage, android-permissions

I recently updated Android Studio to the newest version available (3.5.3), since this moment, I am not able to read or write files on internal or external storage, even though nothing actually changed in my application.

I am trying to access external storage directory with : `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()`

And internal directory with : `Environment.getDataDirectory()`

But then, none of the methods canWrite or canRead returns true, and when I'm trying to access a file on one of these directories, it throws a FileNotFoundException, No such file or directory.

The permission **WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE** appears in my manifest, and I also ask for it at runtime, on the settings of my device, the permission is granted for my app, and if I try to log its value on my app, it also appears as being granted.

FYI, I'm using Gradle version 3.3 and Gradle Plugin version 2.3.3, my app compileSdkVersion is 26, buildToolsVersion 26.0.3 and targetSdkVersion 26

If you need any other information just ask

Any help would be appreciated

**EDIT**

I tried with device plugged / unplugged from the computer, on both cases it isn't working

As requested, here's a snippet where the expression appears

```
File dir = new File(Environment.getDataDirectory().getPath()+"/temp");
String[] files;
files = dir.list();
for (String file : files)
{
    File myFile = new File(dir, file);
    boolean deleteTemp = myFile.delete();
}
```

(I'm, of course, checking if the directory/path exists before, and if not, I create it using mkdirs())

I'm testing over Samsung Galaxy Xcover 4 and 4s, but it seems to appear on every devices, such as Honor 6X and Galaxy S10+

Comment: Please post minimal code that produces the exception

Comment: getDataDirectory or getExternalFilesDir should do it without permissions.

Comment: Post your device details as well.

Comment: I edited my post, please check

Comment: @blackapps , that's what I believed for getDataDirectory and getExternalFilesDir, until now, the error never occured before

Comment: You try to delete a file but are not checking if it exist.

Comment: Why trying to delete all files and subdirs in a directory? Better try to create somewhere one file.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
File dir = new File(Environment.getDataDirectory().getAbsolutePath()+ File.separator +"/temp");
```

use this for checking accessibility:

```
public static String getDataRoot() {
            try {
                if (Environment.getExternalStorageState().equals(Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED) ||
                        (Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().exists() && Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().canWrite())) {
                    return Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath();
                } else {
                    return Environment.getDataDirectory().getAbsolutePath();
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                return null;
            }
        }
```

also, you can read/write temp files on the external cache dir

```
public boolean deleteTemp(Context context) {

    if (context == null) return false;
    File dir = new File(context.getExternalCacheDir() + File.separator + "temp");
    String[] files;
    boolean deleteTemp = false;
    files = dir.list();
    for (String file : files) {
        File myFile = new File(dir, file);
        deleteTemp = myFile.delete();
    }

    return deleteTemp
}
```